# How to use Dialog OnClick Listner in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

I am new to Android development. Please excuse me If my question is very simple.

I have tried to create a button on my Android Layout view using XML. Now within the Activity class I am trying to get the button and add a on click listner to it. This is working fine without any issues.

On similar lines on the button click i explained previously I have a dialog being popped up. In this dialog I have a ImageButton. On click of this Image button I am trying to set a on click listner using the below code.

```
 The Activity on create is as below
```

@Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);        
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
final Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
         if(v==btnAdd) {
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Test Title.");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            dialog.show();

        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        try {
            Log.i("Log","1");
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            Log.i("Log","2");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Log","3");
            dialog.dismiss();
            //Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            //d.setTitle("test.");
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Log","4");
            //d.show();
            Log.i("Log","5");

        }
     }

}
```

In the above I get the Log in this sequence. 1,3,4,5. I dont get the 2. In the toast i get message of blank, blank followed by java.lang.Nullexception.

But this when executed gives me a force close pop up. Please advice how to do this. Or is there any workaround for the same? I need to have a dialog box to come on a button click, and then within the dialog I need to have more than one option of buttons. For each of buttons in the dialog I need to perform different activities. Any kind of help or advice is appreciable. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What exception do you get? Please show logcat output

Comment: Are you using an custom layout for the dialog?

Comment: Yes I am using custom layout for dialog. Is that wrong?

Comment: Full source code of Dialog creation will help us to help you

Comment: I have modified the code. Please have a look and let me know if you need more details. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are trying to retrieve the button from the `Activity` class. It returns null because this method will only retrieve resources attached to the Activity (by using the method `setContentView`).

You have two options:

- You can inflate the dialog layout using a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)
- If you are extending the Dialog class, add the listener inside that class instead.

**Edit after the update:**

As I said above, the problem is:

```
   final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

because imageButton1 is not part of the layout in the activity. Just replace it by:

```
   final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Comment: And I agree too. Button is retrieved from the Activity.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this out shortly and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It helped me to understand the issue. This change worked for me. :-)